# Outlook 2016 inserting thin lines underneath nested tables

Tags: html, css, outlook

I've been having an issue with how outlook has been displaying table HTML for a while now, and I have not been able to resolve this issue for the life of me. Basically, there's a line that cuts through the containing `<td>` when nesting tables (see the slight gray line in the attached image to the right of the purple `<td>`).

[image: Image1]

This is on email's code I've been working with as an example.

```css
<style type="text/css">

   
    @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
  
  .templateColumns{
   width: 100% !important;
  }
  
  .body-text {
   font-size: 16px !important;
  }
  
  .body-about-us {
   font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  
  .center-align {
   text-align: center !important;
  } 
  
  .column-image {
   height:auto !important;
            max-width:480px !important;
            width: 100% !important;
  }
  .column-container {
   display: block !important;
   width: 100% !important;

  }
  
  .sociologos-container {
   text-align: center !important;
   margin-left: auto !important;
   margin-right: auto !important;
   padding-top: 15px !important;
   padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  
  .mopad-left {
   padding-left: 15px !important;
  }
  .mopad-right {
   padding-right: 15px !important;
  }
  
  .mopad-top {
   padding-top: 15px !important;
  }
  .mopad-bottom {
   padding-bottom: 15px !important;
  }
  
  .mopad-button-bottom {
   padding-bottom: 30px !important;
  }
  
  .nopad-bottom {
   padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  } 
  
  .nopad-top {
   padding-top: 0 !important;
  }
  
  .nopad-left {
   padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
  
  .nopad-right {
   padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  
  .modisplay-none {
   display: none !important;
  } 
  
  .mainbtn {
            max-width: 450px !important;
            width: 100% !important;
   margin-top: 10px !important;
        }

        .mainbtn a{
            display:block !important;
  }
  
  .mobold {
   font-weight: bold !important;
  } 
  
  .heading {
   font-size: 32px !important;
   line-height: 36px !important;
  }
  
  .heading2 {
   font-size: 24px !important;
   line-height: 28px !important;
  } 
  
  .heading3 {
   font-size: 20px !important;
   line-height: 20px !important;
  } 
  
  .sociologos {
   width: 32px !important;
   height: 32px !important;
  }
  
  .join-us {
   text-align: center !important;
  }
 }
 p {margin-bottom: 25px; 
 margin-top:10px;}
</style>
```

```html
<body vlink="#421b3e" style="margin:0; padding: 0; background-color:#f2f2f2;"><!--this sets the visited link color, a background color and eliminates any potential auto padding on the page-->
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#333333;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;">
</div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%" id="bodytable" style="background-color:#f2f2f2; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
 <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:0px;">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="580" class="templateColumns mopad-bottom nopad-top mopad-left mopad-right" style=" background-color: #f2f2f2; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 25px; margin:0;">
    
    <!-- start PURPLE HEADER -->
    <tr>
     <td width="100%" align="center" valign="top" class="templateColumns mopad-left mopad-right mopad-top mopad-bottom" id="logo" style="margin:0; background-color: #f2f2f2; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
      LOREM IPSUM   
     </td>
    </tr>
                
    <!-- end PURPLE HEADER -->
    
    
    <!-- start INTRO SECTION -->
    <tr>
     <td align="center" valign="top" class="templateColumns" width="100%" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: margin:0;"><img class="column-image" src="http://go.advicentsolutions.com/rs/841-KAP-325/images/FosteringGrowth2016TitleBanner.png" alt="Nurturing Growth" width="580" style="display:block;" /></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end INTRO SECTION -->
                
    <!-- start FIRST CONTENT SECTION -->
     
     <tr>
     <td width="100%" class="mopad-left mopad-right mkteditable" id="primary-content" style="background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:30px; padding-left:40px; padding-right:40px;">
      <!--<h3 class="body-text mopad-right mopad-left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; color: #3c3d42; letter-spacing: -.25px; line-height: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; margin:0; padding: 0 0 5px 0; ">Did you know?</h3>-->
       <p class="heading2" style="text-align:center; font-size: 28px; color: #3c3d42; line-height: 30px;">lorem ipsum</p>
      <p class="margin" style="text-align:center; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #727577; line-height: 22px; font-weight: 400; ">lorem ipsum</p>
      <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="60%" style="background-color:#6a3757; border-radius: 2px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding:2px; margin: auto;">
       <tr>
        <td align="center" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; border-radius: 4px; background-color: #6a3757; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><strong>lorem ipsum</strong></td>
       </tr> 
      </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end MAIN CTA BUTTON -->
    
    
    
      
    
    <!-- start SOCIAL MEDIA SECTION -->
    <tr>
     <td width="100%" class="templateColumns mopad-bottom mopad-top mopad-left mopad-right" id="social-media" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #f2f2f2; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; margin:0; ">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="column-container join-us" width="50%" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #3c3d42; ">
         Join the Community!
          </td>
          <td aLOREM IPSUM class="column-container"  width="50%">
         <table cellpadding="0" class="sociologos-container" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
          <tr>
           <td align="left" class="sociologos" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px;"><img border="0" style="display: block; padding-left: 5px;" class="sociologos" src="http://www.advicentsolutions.com/images/email/google_42.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Google Plus" /></td>
           <td align="left" class="sociologos" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px;">><img border="0" style="display: block; padding-left: 5px;" class="sociologos" src="http://www.advicentsolutions.com/images/email/twitter_42.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Twitter" /></td>
           <td align="left" class="sociologos" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px;"><img border="0" style="display: block; padding-left: 5px;" class="sociologos" src="http://www.advicentsolutions.com/images/email/facebook_42.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Facebook" /></td>
           <td align="left" class="sociologos" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px;"><img border="0" style="display: block; padding-left: 5px;" class="sociologos" src="http://www.advicentsolutions.com/images/email/linked_42.png" width="32" height="32" alt="LinkedIn" /></td>
           <td align="left" class="sociologos" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px;"><img border="0" class="sociologos" style="display: block; padding-left:5px;" src="http://www.advicentsolutions.com/images/email/youtube_42.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Youtube Channel" /></td>
          
          </tr>
         </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end SOCIAL MEDIA SECTION -->
    
    
    <!-- start DISCLAIMER -->
    <tr>
     <td align="left" valign="top" width="100%" class="templateColumns mopad-bottom mopad-top mopad-left mopad-right" id="disclaimer" style="color:#727577; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-left: 5px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:10px; margin:0;">
     LOREM ISPUM
     </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end DISCLAIMER -->
      
     
   </table>
  </td>
   </tr>
</table>
    
</body>
```

It displays fine as HTML, but I send mostly B2B stuff which means we're always trying to optimize for office. Sometimes the sizing of the banner image can affect it, but other than that one factor, when this happens seems completely arbitrary. It's the one Outlook workaround I haven't been able to figure out. Is there something in my code I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finnnaaalllly found the solution about ten min after posting this. Trick was to remove the padding inline css that was tied to the Lorem ipsum text within the table in the code.

I also fixed this in other instances where `<p>` tags applied to links in the tds also caused issue. Removing the `<p>` tags around the links within the table and any padding accompanying it fixes the issue.